# Como castear un byte[] a File de Java

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo una tabla que contiene un campo blob (varbinary) en SQLSERVER, alli se guardan "Files" de Java.

El software original cuando sube un fichero guarda el "File" como binario en la tabla y guarda el fichero especifico en una carpeta

Quiero recuperar el path de esos ficheros y para eso hice una query nativa de esta manera

```
Query  myquery = em.createNativeQuery("select cast(CBlob as VARBINARY) as a from mytableBlob");
 list1 = myquery.getResultList().toArray();
```

La query se ejecuta bien y me trae los blobs, pero ahora necesito castear cada elemento a un File para poder acceder al metodo .getabsolutepath

No estoy pudiendo encontrar informacion en la red sobre esto

Comment: ¿Necesitas el path para leer el contenido?

Comment: El objeto File en la base de datos no tiene "el contenido2 real del fichero, ese fichero PDF. GIF, etc esta almacenado en otro lado, lo que yo quiero es leer ese array como File para poder obtener el path y nombre

Comment: El caso es que, sin conocer SQLSERVER, dudo que la ruta que te devuelva un File construido a partir de ese byte[] coincida con la ruta de ese "otro lado".

Comment: Cuando en una clase de Java tienes un atributo File (ejemplo File adjunto;) la base de datos (sea cual sea) genera una tabla de varbynary, luego cuando subes un fichero le indicas una ruta y el ORM guarda en el File los datos de ese fichero pero... el fichero en si mismo se guarda en la ruta y no en la base. Lo que quiero hacer es obtener el abstracto File desde la base

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob(column);
InputStream entrada = blob.getBinaryStream();
OutputStream salida = new FileOutputStream(nombreimagen);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
int len = 0;

while ((len = entrada.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    salida.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero el blob no contiene el fichero, solo el binario abstracto de Java, quiero cargarlo en memoria y de alli poner: algo asi File fichero= elfilerecuperadoenmemora, luego fichero.getabsolutepath